# Why does str.capitalize() not work as I expect?

Tags: python

Please, let me know if I'm not providing enough information. The goal of the program is to capitalize the first letter of every sentence.

```
usr_str = input()

def fix_capitalization(usr_str):
  list_of_sentences = usr_str.split(".")
  list_of_sentences.pop() #remove last element: ""
  new_str = ''
  for sentence in list_of_sentences:
    new_str += sentence.capitalize() + "."
  return new_str

print(fix_capitalization(usr_str))
```

For instance, if I input "hi. hello. hey." I expect it to output "Hi. Hello. Hey." but instead, it outputs "Hi. hello. hey."

Comment: The first character of the strings is a space and not a letter.

Comment: If you printed each string adding quotes around it you would have seen for the split sentences after the first that the first character is not a letter. Use `strip()` on each split sentence to remove leading/trailing spaces.

Comment: You can even try "hi. hello. hey.".title()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be to build a list of strings then concatenate them:

```
def fix_capitalization(usr_str):
  list_of_sentences = usr_str.split(".")
  
  output = []
  for sentence in list_of_sentences:
    new_sentence = sentence.strip().capitalize()
    # If empty, don't bother
    if new_sentence:
      output.append(new_sentence)
  
  # Finally, join everything
  return ". ".join(output) +"."
```

Answer (score 0):

You've entered the sentences with spaces between them. Now when you split the list the list at the '.' character the spaces are still remaining. I checked what the elements in the list were when you split it and the result was this.

'''

['hi', ' hello', ' hey', '']

'''

Comment: Yeah I realized that when I used usr_str.split("."), it kept the spaces infront of the letters. I fixed it by replacing new_str += sentence.capitalize() + ". " with new_str += sentence.strip().capitalize() + ". " and then adding new_str = new_str[:len(new_str)] after!

Comment: Nice one, so the whitespace is tripped then you capitalise.